# Exibir inputText de acordo com a quantidade selecionada no Picker React-native

Tags: react-native, jsx

Tenho o seguinte problema.

Tenho um componete Piker com a quantidade e quero que a partir da seleção da quantidade eu obtenha o mesmo numero de TextInput definido pela seleção da quantidade.

Componente Quantidade:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Picker, View } from "react-native";


export default function Pic() {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState("Selecionar");
  return (
      <Picker
        selectedValue={selectedValue}
        style={{ height: 50, width: '100%'}}
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedValue(itemValue)}
      >
        <Picker.Item label="Selecionar:" value="" />
        <Picker.Item label="1" value={1}/>
        <Picker.Item label="2" value={2}/>
        <Picker.Item label="3" value={3}/>
        <Picker.Item label="4" value={4}/>
        <Picker.Item label="5" value={5}/>
        <Picker.Item label="6" value={6}/>
        <Picker.Item label="7" value={7}/>
        <Picker.Item label="8" value={8}/>
      </Picker>


  );
}
```

Componente TextInput:

```
    import React from 'react'
import { View, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'


export default props => {
    const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState('Digite aqui...');

    return (
        <View style={[styles.container, props.style]}>
            <TextInput onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
      value={value} style={styles.input} />
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        width: '90%',
        height: 40,
        backgroundColor: '#EEE',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 15,
        marginLeft: 20,
    },
    input: {
        width: '70%',
        
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um array a partir da quantidade selecionada no seu Picker e esse array retorna para você os TextInput's. Mais ou menos desse jeito:

```
export default function Screen() {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState(0);
  return (
    <View>
      // ... Picker
      {new Array(selectedValue).map(() => (
        <TextInput />
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}
```

Lembre-se que o `state` que você cria dentro do seu componente customizado é exclusivo do componente, você não vai conseguir acessa-lo a partir da tela que "segura" ele. O mesmo vale para o seu componente de Quantidade, por isso no exemplo que fiz, o `state` do componente de Quantidade ficaria na tela e não no componente.

Comment: Não deu certo. Os imputes não aparecem.

Comment: Você chegou a ver se o map está sendo realizado? Se você deixou o Picker em um componente separado, verifique se você está "setando" o state no lugar certo. Confira também se os Inputs estão sendo retornados no map.

Comment: Eu coloquei como componente, pois estou utilizando classe na tela principal.

Comment: export default class Home extends Component {<Colaboradores/>}